# Twenty Fourteen: Hide Header Image on mobile phone

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using the wordpress theme "Twenty Fourteen". I would like to hide the header image on mobile phone size screens. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it. Is there anybody who knows how to do it? 
Thank you a lot!
Best wishes, 
pradhana

Comment: Do you have a link to your site?

Comment: Sure. www.veda-vit.de

Comment: which image do you want to hide in the header?

Comment: Now I added a header image (Header2.jpg). I want to hide it on mobile phone.

Comment: I have updated my answer for your image just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a media query to your style.css file:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  #site-header > a > img {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

This will remove your header image for any devices with a screen smaller than 481 pixels.